# Moodle Scorm API throws an error

Tags: moodle, scorm

I'm running Moodle 2.4.3. Seems like I have issues with my Scorm API. It throws an error at the end of last slide.

"Trying to set value but API not available."

[image: Moodle Scorm API error]

What could be the reason?

BTW, I'm using Google Chrome 44.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that this is happening at the end of the package suggests to me that the package is closing the connection and then trying to send more data.

Have you tried running the course on [SCORM Cloud](http://cloud.scorm.com) in debug mode to see what's going on?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I haven't tried SCORM Cloud. Can you tell me how can I fix this issue? It's not happening for all users. It's just me.

Comment: If it's what I suggested it could be, you'd need to make a code change in the package. Trying it on SCORM Cloud in debug mode would help to diagnose.